# Print ith bit of the binary number, please find the error as it is printing wrong numbers on some bits

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, number-systems

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int x = 1010110;
        System.out.println("the ith bit is " + ithBit(x, n));
    }

    public static int ithBit(int x, int n) {
        int bitValue = (x & (1 << (n - 1))) != 0 ? 1 : 0;
        return bitValue;
    }
```

in number 1010110, its giving 4th bit=1,6th bit=1, 7th bit=0

Comment: I hope you realize that `int x = 1010110;` is not defining a binary number. Its a decimal number > 1 million and in binary representation would be 11110110100110111110.

Comment: `in number 1010110, its giving 4th bit=1,6th bit=1, 7th bit=0` Thats correct.

Comment: thankyou i got my answer

Comment: @AshishKumar Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  Are you aware what the `dsa` tag is meant for?

Answer (score 0):

This presumes the low order bit is the `0th` bit.  You don't need  to use the conditional operator (`?:`).  Just shift the result back and return the `1` or `0` directly. `>>>` is used to not backfill the sign bit, if detected, when shifting right. Otherwise, you would get `-1` for `ithBit(-1, 31);`

```
public static int ithBit(int x, int n) {
        return  (x & (1 << n)) >>> n;
}
```